# Tabular tooltip in highcharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

How can I show tabular tooltip in Highcharts?
Consider an example: There are students A, B and C and the chart shows marks or subjects X, Y and Z in the chart. The x-axis shows months (in which exams were conducted).

So, totally there are 9 series in the chart. The tooltip shows six rows with marks of all the three students in all the three subjects.

```
Feb '18
A-X: 34
A-Y: 35
A-Z: 36
B-X: 37
B-Y: 38
B-Z: 39
C-X: 40
C-Y: 41
C-Z: 42
```

Rather, I want to show it in a table:

```
Feb'18
|Student Name | X  | Y  | Z  |
|A            | 34 | 35 | 36 |
|B            | 37 | 38 | 39 |
|C            | 40 | 41 | 42 |
```

I am not able to use the `formatter` label of HighCharts to achieve this. May be I am not getting the way.

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: Can you produce a working code snippet demonstrating the problem?

Comment: I still haven't implemented the chart, because I don't know how to achieve this. Thats why I have given an example of 9 series.

Comment: I think this example can help: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/footerformat/